# Changing A DNS record using ModifyDNS() method, reports success but DNSMANAGER disagree

Tags: godaddy-api

I'm working in a solution for my company. I'm using the Godaddy API. The methods Describe(), CheckAvailability(), and OrderDomains() are working perfectly but I'm trying to change the A DNS record with ModifyDNS() method and their response is:

```
[ModifyDNSResult] => 
    <response>
        <result code="1000"/>
            <resdata>ModifyDNS OK</resdata>
    </response>
```

As you can see the result is success but when I check in my DNSMANAGER the IP is the same.

I have read: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101906/changing-a-record-using-godaddy-api, https://api.wildwestdomains.com/wswwdapi/wapi.asmx, https://img1.wsimg.com/Rex/docs/WWDAPI_WebServicev2_5.pdf.

I made a request to Godaddy API support, and after around 20 days they said: "The issue has been addressed and should be resolved at this time" and I still getting the same issue. Anyone know how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because related to goddady customer support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely I moved to http://www.domainbox.com/. Godaddy never answered my requirements with his API.